# Converting from alternation to conditional in mathematical logic

Tags: logic

I have this alternation statement:

```
r V p V ~q
```

I would like to convert it to a conditional, like so (although, I think is wrong and hence where I'm skeptical):

```
r -> p V ~q
```

I'm looking into De Morgan's First and Second Law. I do know a few equivalences that are bound to help, in regard to eliminating conditionals:

1. `p -> q` equivalent to `~p V q`
2. `p V q. -> r` equivalent to `~(p V q) ∨ r`

I can't wrap my head around what would constitute to an allowable conversion, particularly because of that negated `q`. It seems equivalency 1 might work:

Initial statement:

```
r V p V ~q
```

Using equivalency 1:

```
r -> ~(p V ~q)
r -> ~p V q
```

Problem: How do I convert the initial alternation statement into a conditional statement?

Answer (score 1):

You can apply equivalence 1. by "grouping" any 2 of the three disjuncts. For example if $r \lor p$ is grouped it becomes $\lnot (r \lor p) \rightarrow \lnot q.$